How to label axes in Slider2D?
I want to use a Slider2D to vary two quantities a and b. This works, but how do I label each axis?
Manipulate[abf, {{abf, {0, 0}, "{a,b}"}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, 
  ControlType -> Slider2D, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]

I also tried this, but no better.
Manipulate[abf, {{abf, {0, 0}, {"a", "b"}}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1}, 
  ControlType -> Slider2D, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]


$Version

(* "14.1.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (July 16, 2024)" *)

Manipulate[abf,
 Labeled[
  Control[{{abf, {0, 0}, Rotate["<--- b --->", Pi/2]}, {-1, -1}, {1, 1},
    ControlType -> Slider2D,
    Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
  "<--- a --->            ", Top],
 TrackedSymbols :> {abf}]



WRI should include such a labelling function in future releases.
